# Do all the accretion disks around a compact object (black hole or neutron star) emit astrophysical jet outflow?

Tags: astrophysics, accretion-discs, high-energy-astrophysics, accretion, astronomical-jet

Do all the accretion disks around a compact object (black hole or neutron star) emit astrophysical jet outflow? I mean is it mandatory for a jet to be emitted from an accretion disk?

- If so, then why?
- If not, then what is/are the condition(s) for emitting a jet? Are there some examples of systems that clearly don't?

Comment: This is phrased like an exam question. We do not solve your homework. Show us your own research into the topic first, then let's talk.

Comment: No, it's not any exam question or like that. As you are asking about this, let me clear you, what I've not mentioned in the question: this is my mere curiosity to know about this. Nothing else! The beginning point of my curiosity is that **I've not** seen any image of Sagittarius A*, where it is shown to be emitting jet.

Comment: And what you're asking about my research on this topic is that, I searched about this on google. But no related answer I got (maybe I've missed). Then I tried to derive any theoretical condition/constraint(s), which can distinguish the situation of jet emission and no-jet emission. But for some reason, that calculation took me too far away from my original query. So I skipped it to add to my question.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape One thing more to add is that, the question may sound homework-like because there are too many formal questions, that have been asked at once. I have done that intentionally, because after getting the answer of a part of the question, to know the answer of the related queries, I have to repost such a question with the remaining questions again. So...

Comment: @SCh *Welcome to Astronomy SE!* Don't worry about that :-) but your post had six question marks while the title had none, so it was hard to tell exactly what question an answer post should answer here. I've made an edit to your post to slightly restructure it; please feel free to edit further.